# zmq ventilator/worker/sink paradigm not working w/ subprocess

Tags: c++, python, zeromq, pyzmq

I am trying to replicate the ventilator/workers/sink paradigm described in the ZMQ guide.  I have the same Python Ventilator, the same C++ worker as, and the same Python Sink as was described in the ZMQ examples.  I want to launch the ventilator, workers, and sink from one main python script, so I created "class" wrappers around the ventilator & sink, and both of those classes subclass the Python module "multiprocessing.Process."  Since the C++ is a binary, I launch it with Python's subprocess.Popen call.

The order of starting all of this up is as follows:

```
h = subprocess.Popen('test')  # test is the name of the binary
time.sleep(1)
s = sinkObj.start()
time.sleep(1)
v = ventObj.start()
```

What I am finding is that no data is getting through the system when I start up the components like this.  However, if I start the C++ binary in its own shell, and only start the sinkObj and ventObj from the main python script, it works fine.

I apologize in advance if this is more of a Python question than a ZMQ question, but I haven't run into issues like this w/ Python's subprocess.  I have also tried using os.system() instead of the subprocess... but same issue.  I put all the code on this website: https://github.com/kkarrancsu/zmqtest  if anybody is curious to test it out.  There is a readme on that git which tells you what the files are.

Any ideas on why this could be happening?

------------------------- UPDATE --------------------

I found that if I create a shell script which simply launches the C binary, and call that shell script w/ os.system('run_the_shell_script') it works! So this means that there is something wrong with the way that I am using subprocess.Popen(...), but can't seem to pinpoint what the issue is. I tried w/ the shell=True flag, but it still hangs with that...

Answer (score 1):

It's the name of the `worker` binary file that causes the problem.

There two solutions:

- Chang the name of the binary file **test** to **test_new** and do the same in your **All.py** file, and then it will work as you desire.
- Substitute `subprocess.Popen('./test', shell=True)` for `subprocess.Popen('test', shell=True)`.

`test` is Linux command. If you type the following in your shell

```
$ echo $PATH
```

You may see that `.` is at the last position. It means that until shell couldn't find the binary file to be executed in the directories that $PATH indicates, it will try to search for it in the current directory `.`
When you execute `subprocess.Popen('test', shell=True)`, it could find it before trying the `.` directory and so it won't execute the `workers`.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, the ventilator and sink `bind()` to ports 6557 and 6558, and the C++ app `connect()` to these ports. In this case, if you start the `cpp` app first, it will try to `connect()` to the endpoints, but as nothing is bound there, it will drop silently.
In ZeroMQ the basic principle is "First Bind, then Connect". So you should not `connect()` before you `bind()` something on the socket. Imagine `bind()` is the 'Server', and `connect()` is the client. You cannot connect client to non-existing server. Also, in ZeroMQ every socket can be 'Server', but you SHOULD HAVE only 1 bind()-ing socket per URL. And  you can have multiple 'connect()'s.

Comment: I tried your suggestion by moving the `subprocess.Popen` code (which launches the C++ binary that calls `connect()` AFTER starting both the ventilator and sink (which bind), but still same issue.  No data is flowing through when I start the C++ binary from the python with `subprocess.Popen`